# Create Diagonal Tile Map in Phaser.js?

Tags: easeljs, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a web game, and before committing to one language, I need to  decide weather to use Phaser.js or EaselJS. When looking at Phaser.js, it seems all of the tile maps are front on and flat..... [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZoE.png). Is there a way to make a diagonal tile map on Phaser.js.... [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voyxZ.png)?

Thanks

Comment: you are looking for something like this: http://rotates.org/phaser/iso/

Comment: Instead of searching for "diagonal tiles", this is more commonly referred to as **isometric view** or **isometric graphics**.